# Calculating final polygon after subtracting all intersecting polygons using shapely

Tags: python, shapely, loop, intersect, iteration

I have a list of centroids that I buffer to 5000 meters radius. I need to take each resulting circle and run it against the remaining centroids(also buffered to 5000 m) and find the final shape after subtracting all intersections.

In other words, I need the circle shape A to iterate over the dataset, find all circle shape(s) that intersect with it (B and C) and then create a column with a geocoordinates of the polygon, that is resulting after all intersecting circle areas are subtracted (see image below) and if it does not intersect with any other cirlce(s), just add a geocoordinate for the entire circle:

[image]

Here is the code I have:

```
df.head()

# Output: 
#                cell_centroid  pop     id
#0  POINT(21.25602 55.903539)   9004.0  0
#1  POINT(21.119156 55.538406)  517.0   1
#2  POINT(21.249535 55.890204)  10369.0 2
#3  POINT(21.359934 55.904164)  800.0   3
#4  POINT(24.433042 56.104589)   
 
df['cell_centroid'] = df['cell_centroid'].apply(wkt.loads)

for i, r in df.iterrows():
    # take the centroid of interest and buffer it with a 5000 meter radius
    a = gpd.GeoSeries(r['cell_centroid'], crs = 4326).to_crs(crs = 3857).buffer(5000)
    # separate that centroid from df and save the remaining rows as a separate df
    df_dropped = df.drop(i, axis = 0)
    li = [] # an empty list to collect intersections
    # iterate over the separated df to find if the dropped centroid intersects with any of the remaining in the dataset

    for j, s in df_dropped.iterrows():
        # the centroid to be compared with
        b = gpd.GeoSeries(s['cell_centroid'], crs = 4326).to_crs(crs = 3857).buffer(5000)

        # check if the centroid1 intersects with centroid2
        if(a.intersects(b)[0] == True):
            tf = a.intersects(b)[0] 
        # add the intersects to the list
            li.append(tf)
        # create a list of just the True shapes(shapes with which the input shape intersects), using intersects list as an index
        new_df = df_dropped.loc[np.array(li)]

        if len(new_df) > 0:
            print('iteration {} : \n{}'.format(i, new_df))
        else:
            print('iteration {} is empty'.format(i))

        # iterate through True shapes dataset (new_df) and find the difference between input shape and each shape in the new_df.
        if len(new_df) > 1:
            iterator = 1
            for k, t in new_df.iterrows():
                c = gpd.GeoSeries(t['cell_centroid'], crs = 4326).to_crs(crs=3857).buffer(5000)
                tf = a.difference(c)
                col_name = 'intersect' + str(iterator)
                df.loc[:, col_name] = tf
                iterator += 1
        # for each centroid a, put each True value into a separate new column in the orginal dataset
        elif len(new_df) == 1:
            c = gpd.GeoSeries(t['cell_centroid'], crs = 4326).to_crs(crs=3857).buffer(5000)
            tf = a.difference(c)
            # for each centroid a, put each True value into a separate new column in the orginal dataset
            df['intersect1'] = tf
        else:
            continue
```

The error I am getting is:

```
  ---> 34         c = gpd.GeoSeries(t['cell_centroid'], crs = 4326).to_crs(crs=3857).buffer(5000)
       35         tf = a.difference(c)
       36         # for each centroid a, put each True value into a separate new column in the orginal dataset

 NameError: name 't' is not defined
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the most optimal way to calculate final shape (less all intersects) for a each buffered centroid?
2. Why am I getting an error on line 34? t is defined at the beginning of the loop.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed the code as suggested in the answer:

```
df['cell_centroid'] = df['cell_centroid'].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="cell_centroid", crs = 4326).to_crs(crs=3857)

gdf["buffer"] = gdf.buffer(5000)
gdf["difference"] = None

gdf = gdf.set_geometry("buffer")

for i, row in gdf.iterrows():
    others = gdf[gdf["id"] != row["id"]]
    diff = row["buffer"].difference(others.cascaded_union)
    gdf.loc[i, "difference"] = diff

gdf = gdf.set_geometry("difference")
```

The error I am getting now is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-122-ad757ced6ebf> in <module>
      3     diff = row["buffer"].difference(others.cascaded_union)
      4 #    gdf.loc[i, "difference"] = gpd.GeoSeries(diff)
----> 5     gdf.loc[i, "difference"] = diff
...

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable'
```

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz done, thank you

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz fixed, my apologies.

Comment: Could you add a sample image representing what exactly you try to achieve. I read your question for a while, I cannot understand. I have not encountered the error you mentioned yet, because I get different errors before that line.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz done. Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I am getting an error using your solution. Please see the comment under your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of `len(new_df) == 1`, since `t` is not defined in `elif`, you get the error. That means the first block of `if` never runs before you get the error. Even if the first block worked once, you would get the wrong result after all. Because `t` would be `t` coming from previous iteration, not from current iteration.

In case of `len(new_df) > 1`, first block of `if` statement processes. Since `t` is defined by `for` loop, you won't get an error for the first block of `if`.

To get rid of that error, add `t = new_df.iloc[0]` under `elif` before `c = gpd...`. You may encounter different errors though.

---

The more optimal script:

```
df['cell_centroid'] = df['cell_centroid'].apply(wkt.loads)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="cell_centroid", crs = 4326).to_crs(crs=3857)

gdf["buffer"] = gdf.buffer(5000)
gdf["difference"] = None

gdf = gdf.set_geometry("buffer")

for i, row in gdf.iterrows():
    others = gdf[gdf["id"] != row["id"]]
    diff = row["buffer"].difference(others.cascaded_union)
    gdf.loc[i, "difference"] = diff

gdf = gdf.set_geometry("difference")

gdf.plot() # I use a custom method to draw
```

The result for a toy data:

[image]

Comment: I am getting an ValueError at 
'----> 4     gdf.loc[i, "difference"] = diff' line: ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: Did you ever solve this?